# Как заверстать такую сетку?

Tags: вёрстка, flexbox, grid

Вот картинка. Как можно это заверстать, с учетом того что количество брендов и букв всегда меняется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сейчас начал через гриды, но сразу ступор:

.Brands{
     border: 1px solid red;

```
 height: auto;
 max-width: 1350px;
 margin: 1% auto;
 display: grid;

 grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25%;
 grid-auto-flow: row;

}

.card{
  height: auto;

  border: 1px dashed #a9a9a9;
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто несколько колонок, то можете обратить внимание на многоколоночную верстку:

```css
/* visual styles */

.parent {
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid navy;
  padding:10px;
  column-count:3;
}

.child {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red inset;
  background-color: #fdb;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* main styles */
.parent {
  column-count:3;
}

.child {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<div class="child">
    <h1>A</h1>
    item 1<br>
    item 2<br>
    item 3<br>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <h1>B</h1>
    item 1<br>
    item 2<br>
    item 3<br>
    item 4<br>
    item 5<br>
    item 6<br>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <h1>C</h1>
    item 1<br>
    item 2<br>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <h1>D</h1>
    item 1<br>
    item 2<br>
    item 3<br>
</div>

</div>
```

А так - просто засуньте блоки на каждую букву в четыре колонки.

Answer (score 0):

Всё это называется masonry.

Мне под react очень круто помог этот пакет [react-masonry-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-css)

[image: Вот результат:]

Comment: это хорошо, но требует засрать проект очередным фреймворком